# Ground wire in the house but not in the fixture?

Tags: electrical, light-fixture

I have been reading some posts here and am still unclear.  I have an old fixture that I want to install.  The fixture does not have a ground wire.  Just white and black.  My ceiling wires have a ground as well as one white and one black.

Do I simply attach the bare copper to the ceiling box with a screw?  I have tested to see if the ground wire is properly grounded by putting my tester on the bare copper and the black.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Does the fixture have a substantial amount of metal that could be grounded? Will it get bonded to the box when you mount it? (A picture could be helpful.)

Comment: Is the fixture likely to be touched by anyone in normal use (once it's mounted)?

Comment: The fixture isn't likely to be touched by anyone after it is installed.  I intent to screw the ground wire #1 into the screw hole #2 then mount the light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many light fixtures are not grounded. If once installed there is no exposed metal even a brand new UL listed fixture may not have a ground. With a metal box the ground wire should be attached to the box by code. Once you connect the fixture to the box it would be grounded if it needed it.

Comment: Thank you for confirming what I had in my head